# Leading user to new activity clicking on item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

[image]
ListView is created from Cursor with data from DB.

Clicking on each **item** in ListView leads user to a new Activity/Page/Layout/WHAT? where additional info + pictures about the **item** are shown.

Do I need to create dynamic activities? Or there is a better way that I just do not know about?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic activities"?

Comment: for every item create new activity with all necessary data shown when user clicks the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each item has a sufficiently common format for displaying your "additional info + pictures", then I would suggest creating a single Activity to represent your items, and then fill in the details by passing the item as an extra on the Intent that launches your activity. For example,

In the list activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ITEM_DETAILS_INTENT);
intent.putExtra(ITEM_NAME, itemName);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the item detail activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String itemName = intent.getStringExtra(ITEM_NAME);
populateDetails(itemName);
```

On the other hand, if "Controls" requires a significantly different format from "Focus", you'll need a ControlsActivity and FocusActivity (for example) where each activity handles each item, and you launch a different activity depending on the item selected.

Hope this helps!